# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' Error while gradle build

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to add an library to the android application. I have added library as dependency in the project settings. 
Then when I tried building the project, gradle shows below error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I searched for it and found many solutions, but none of it is working in my case. Please find below my app build.gradle and library build.gradle files

app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.application.package"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':library')
}
```

and library build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "v0.1L"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

also, find below my project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am stuck in this  issue for complete 1 day. Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks,
Rajan

Comment: Anybody has any input on above issue. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...

}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...

}
```